Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}dx$
I'm trying to evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1 dx}$. I came across this post detailing a solution to it, and wanted to ask if my solution is correct:

Firstly, let $f_n(x) = g_n(x) h(x)$, where $g_n(x) = ne^{-nx}$ and $h(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1 dx}$. My idea is that, for $x \approx 0$, we have that $f_n \approx g_n$, and since the latter has considerable mass near the origin, resulting in $\int_0^{\infty} g_n = 1$, so should our $f_n$.

First, for an easy upper bound on $\int f_n$, we have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}} f_n \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}} g_n = 1$.

Let us now work towards a lower bound with the above intuition.


To make "$f_n \approx g_n$" rigorous, we note that $h$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, so that $1 - \epsilon < h < 1$ for some $\eta$ and $x \in (0,\eta)$. Thus, for $x \in (0,\delta)$ for some $0 < \delta < \eta$, we have $g_n(1 - \epsilon) < f_n < g_n$, so that $\int_0^{\delta} f_n > (1-\epsilon) \int_0^{\delta} g_n = (1-\epsilon)(1-e^{-n \delta})$.
In particular, for $\delta \equiv \delta(n) := \omega(\frac{1}{n}) $, so that $n \delta = \frac{\delta}{1/n} \rightarrow  \infty$, and such that $\delta(n) \rightarrow 0$ (for example, take $\delta(n) = \frac{1}{n^a}, 0 < a < 1$), we have that $\int_0^{\delta(n)} f_n > (1 - \epsilon)$ for all $n$ sufficiently large (specifically, such that $\delta(n) < \eta$).
But then, $\int_0^{\infty} f_n > \int_0^{\delta(n)} f_n > 1 - \epsilon$, as well. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, and by our upper bound above, we get that $\lim_n \int_{(0,\infty)} f_n = 1$.

Too long for a comment and just for your curiosity.
This looks fine to me.
If you want to go further with bounds, write
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{x^2+1}{(x-a)(x-b)}=1+\frac{a^2+1}{(a-b) (x-a)}-\frac{b^2+1}{(a-b) (x-b)}$$ and use
$$\int \frac {e^{-nx}}{x-c}\,dx=e^{-c n}\,\, \text{Ei}(-n(x-c))$$ where appears the exponential integral function.
Since $c$ is a complex, there is no problem to compute the definite integral. The resulting formula is quite nasty but its asymptotics are simple
$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\,dx=1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{24}{n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ which gives tight bounds.

For this integral, a change of variables allows to write the integral of interest as integrals of a  rescaling of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^1+1}{x^2+x+1}$ with respect to a fixed probability distribution. The integrals thus obtained are easier to deal with by well known convergence theorems such as dominated convergence.
To be precise, the change of variables $u=nx$ yields
$$I_n=\int^\infty_0ne^{-nx}\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\,dx=\int^\infty_0 e^{-u}\frac{u^2+n^2}{u^2+nu+n^2}\,du
$$
The sequence of functions $f_n(u)=\frac{u^2+n^2}{u^2+nu+n^2}$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$, in fact $0<f_n(u)\leq1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(u)=1$.  Dominated convergence implies that
$$\lim_nI_n=\int^\infty_0 e^{-u}\lim_n f_n(u)\,du=\int^\infty_0 e^{-u}\,du=1$$

Edit:  If the OP is familiar with probability theory, in particular characteristic functions and the Levy continuity theorem the integral $I_n$ can be seen as he expectation of the continuous and bounded function $f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$ with respect to the exponential distribution $P_n$ with parameter $n$. As $n\rightarrow\infty$, $P_n$ converges to the $\delta_0$ distribution. Indeed, the characteristic function of $P_n$ is
$$\hat{P}_n(t)=\int^\infty_0 e^{itx}ne^{-nx}\,dx=\frac{n}{n-it}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1=\int^\infty_0 e^{itx}\delta_0(dx)$$
Then, $P_n\Longrightarrow\delta_0$ and so,
$$I_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\delta_0(dx)=f(0)=1$$
